# For binary bson fields, does mongo use the sub-type for any reason

Tags: mongodb, bson

I have a binary field that I'm storing in mongo. The value is an MD5 hash at the moment, but there's a chance this could change in the future. I'm trying to decide what bson binary subtype to use. Specifically, I'm not sure if I should use BSON.BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT or BSON.BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_MD5. Is mongo able to use this subtype in order to perform any sort of optimizations? For example, can it build smarter indexes if it knows the value is an MD5?

Comment: But those subtypes are just part of the BSON specification, it does not have to see something with the MongoDB server per se, in the database everything is stored as BSON, the subtypes are enum types that you use in your application.

Comment: @Euclides I guess that's my question. Are the subtypes just for application side logic, or does Mongo utilize those subtypes for any sort of optimizations?

Comment: yes, it is only for application side logic.  There is something named a hashed index, but according to the documentation MongoDB supports hashed indexes of any single field, but even so, it is not about the subtypes that you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks @Euclides. Is that documented somewhere? If you could submit this as an answer with a link I'd gladly mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can store a hashed index using "hidden" bindata keys.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/

If you never wish to perform a wildcard query fielded by this particular index, a hash index can "shrink" or "expand" an indexable field down/up to a known size.  This means that you could index a very long string (4MB long) using an index key of length specified by the hashing function (perhaps 32 bytes long)

The application doesn't need to know anything about the hashing function or the internals, you'd only see faster query results at the expense of potential but exceedingly unlikely hash collisions.

Then there is also bitwise bindata operators available to the application, including which type of bindata you want store.  A most obvious use case is a web application storing logs, including user IP address as binary data and the user defined subtype.

Your query can use the $bitsAllSet to use standard netmasks to query what connections had been made from a particular network range.  MongoDB is perfectly capable to check that

1. the document's key contains the correct subtype (user defined and
   not UUID/MD5)
2. if the first match passes, it'll perform the
   slightly more expensive bitwise operation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query-bitwise/